# Canon 50mm f/1.8 STM vs Nikon 50mm f/1.8G lens?

Tags: 50mm

Is there anyway we can do some kind of comparison between these two prime lenses from Canon and Nikon respectively?

Things to look for are - CA, Bokeh/color fringing, Bokeh ball rounding, sharpness etc.

Comment: They are similar.

Comment: For what purpose do you wish to compare them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, there are multiple sites that let you head-to-head shots of test charts against each other or test results.

- [the-digital-picture.com's shot comparison](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=989&Camera=453&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=766&CameraComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0)
- [dxomark.com's test results comparison](http://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Compare/Side-by-side/Canon-EF-50mm-F18-STM-on-Canon-EOS-5DS-R-versus-Nikon-AF-S-Nikkor-50mm-F18G-on-Nikon-D800E__1541_1009_435_814)

But whether or not you get any meaningful information about how they perform in use in the field is questionable.

The reality is that these are very similar lenses: low-cost, relatively simple construction, and fast primes. Same focal length, same max. aperture. They'll behave very similarly, and trying to find something to choose between them is like splitting hairs, and about as practical. You're unlikely to use both, since few shooters have both Canon and Nikon systems (and those who do probably don't care about 50/1.8 lenses), so which one you'd want is determined by which mount system you shoot in.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, take a picture of the same subject with the same lens settings and the same lighting conditions, using film Canon/Nikon SLRs loaded with the same film stock. Develop the film and compare the results.

You can use a lens before buying it by renting. Rent the two lenses. Also rent a camera, such as a Sony A7R (or other E-mount camera), along with a Canon-EF-to-Sony-E adapter and Nikon-F-to-Sony-E adapter. By using the exact same camera, the only differences in the shots will be due to the lenses (and perhaps your own technique).

Comment: I need to know before buying the lens. :)

Comment: Have you tried Google? There must be at least half a dozen articles (pointlessly) comparing these two lenses, not to mention comparison sites like Photodo, etc.

Comment: @MGRashed You should buy the one that is the same brand as your camera. If you don't yet have a camera, then you should not use the comparison of these particular two lenses as the deciding factor for which camera to buy - these are simple, basic lenses and there are more important deciding factors when buying a camera.

Answer (score 4):

I'm curious why you want to compare these lenses? Surely you're not trying to decide whether to buy a Canon or Nikon camera based on the quality of their consumer-grade nifty fifty?

There are so many other factors like sensors (Canon insists designing their own mediocre ones, while Nikon uses the best it can get [usually Sony]), ergonomics, metering systems (Canon can't hold a candle to Nikon), AF systems (Nikon has mostly caught up with Canon), and more, which are more important than the cheapest and most quickly outgrown lens in each system's line-up.

This is even more true because neither of the lenses you mentioned are as good as the Sigma 50/1.4 Art or Tamron 45/1.8 (or more expensive manual focus Zeiss Milvus 50/1.4 & Otus 55/1.4) which are all available for either system.

Comment: I've found Canon's *Evaluative* metering to be superior to Nikon's *Matrix* metering. At least in the upper tier bodies with RGBir light meters and processors dedicated to metering. And there's no comparison between the top AF systems of Canon to Nikon's best AF systems. The new D5 may have closed the gap to the 1D X a little, but here comes the 1D X Mark II in a month or so with 61 AF points *all sensitive to f/8* and 41 of them cross type points. And while Nikon sensors are currently a little better than Canon's, *mediocre* to *best it can get* is a bit of a stretch, especially since...

Comment: ...Nikon and Sony have apparently parted ways for the short term future.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but why do say Canon's sensors are mediocre?  I would have described them as *market leading*, and I'm a Nikon shooter.

Comment: Good answer. Would be even better without the subjective assertions.

Comment: Downvoted for the biased and irrelevant assertions. The parenthetical clauses add nothing useful to the answer (Full disclosure: I'm a Canon shooter.)

Comment: The AF comment, based on my own D4 vs 1D X experiences, is subjective because there are so many factors which can affect AF success rate in a sporting event. However, I put the D800 and 5D3 on a tripod and pointed them at the same scenes on the same day in the same light and the difference in how often I needed exposure compensation is huge and objectively measurable. Consult DXOMark for objective proof of the inferiority of Canon's sensors. Consult any number of comparison tests (I favor Roger Cicala's bench measurements as a starting point) for my comments on the lenses.

Answer (score 4):

They're fine. This is an easy lens design, but they're also made to be low cost, without a lot of glass or super-exotic elements. For the purposes of actual photography (as opposed to benchmark scores), there is virtually no difference.

It sounds like you are using this comparison to choose between systems. I wouldn't recommend that. The actual impact to your work will be negligible. And, anyway, it's just one budget lens — other lenses may be different, and anyway both companies offer great lenses in all price ranges, including fancier 50mm options. (And not just Canon or Nikon — same with Pentax and Sony. And there are great third party lenses for all of these systems, too. )

If,  on the other hand, you want to know in order to settle some wrestling match over which brand is more awesome — well, okay, that's a funny hobby, but I know many people enjoy it. There *are* plenty of reviews out there, and you can probably cherry pick your favorites in order to support your side.

Answer (score -2):

I just found out that the Nikon model is sharp @f1,8 and the Canon isn't :(

--

I received some die votes which I understand so here some more details:

I compared the sharpness measurement of the 2 lenses on dxomark:

[Canon 50mm STM](https://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Canon/Canon-EF-50mm-F18-STM-mounted-on-Canon-EOS-5DS-R---Measurements__1009)

[Nikkor 50mm 1.8G](https://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Nikon/Nikon-AF-S-Nikkor-50mm-F18G-mounted-on-Nikon-D800E---Measurements__814)

On these 2 pages you are able to see sharpness charts[image: sharpness Nikkor (image from dxomark)]
Nikkor sharpness
[image: sharpness Canon]Sharpness Canon EF

As you can see the Canon version is not that good whose open (red bad - green good) whereas Nikon's lens starts with light green which already is good. (More expensive Canon 50mm lenses perform similarly,so the price difference is not the best argument!

Comment: And... the Canon lens was tested on a 50MP body, while the Nikon one was used on a 36MP body. You don't think that _might_ have had something to do with the differences DXO recorded?

Comment: It's very similar for lower resolution bodies https://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Canon/Canon-EF-50mm-F18-STM-mounted-on-Canon-EOS-760D---Measurements__1011 https://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Nikon/Nikon-AF-S-Nikkor-50mm-F18G-mounted-on-Nikon-D5300---Measurements__919 Still much sharper wide open